# Dropdown list disappers on Android JB webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, webview

My android app has webview on with the url sent from a server is rendered. Also the server keep sending some messages in JSON format every 3 seconds which I need to provide it to the app on my mobile.
The online page rendered on the mobile webview as some drop down list. Whenever I select drop down box, it automatically disappears before i select anything from the drop down list.

I observed that as soon as the server sends me the messages, this drop down list will disappear. If I stop receiving the messages from server, the drop down list stays on screen. but I cant stop the messages reaching my android application.

And this is observed only on jelly bean devices. Kitkat devices works fine for same scenario.